# Extending Request in typescript compiles to ES5 with TypeError

Tags: class, typescript, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to extend `Request` class in Typescript as follows:

```
export class ApiRequest extends Request {
    static userAgentHeader: string = '';
    static xUserAgentHeader: string = '';

    public body: string;

    constructor(url: string, initialData?: any) {
        super(url, initialData);

        if (this.method !== 'GET') {
            this.body = initialData._bodyText;
        }

        this.headers.set('User-Agent', ApiRequest.userAgentHeader);
        this.headers.set('X-User-Agent', ApiRequest.xUserAgentHeader);
    }

    static setAgentHeader(userAgentHeader: string) {
        ApiRequest.userAgentHeader = userAgentHeader;
    }

    static setXUserAgentHeader(xUserAgentHeader: string) {
        ApiRequest.xUserAgentHeader = xUserAgentHeader;
    }
}
```

However when transpilling to ES5 I'm getting following piece of code:

```
import * as tslib_1 from "tslib";
var ApiRequest = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    tslib_1.__extends(ApiRequest, _super);
    function ApiRequest(url, initialData) {
        var _this = _super.call(this, url, initialData) || this;
        if (_this.method !== 'GET') {
            _this.body = initialData._bodyText;
        }
        _this.headers.set('User-Agent', ApiRequest.userAgentHeader);
        _this.headers.set('X-User-Agent', ApiRequest.xUserAgentHeader);
        return _this;
    }
    ApiRequest.setAgentHeader = function (userAgentHeader) {
        ApiRequest.userAgentHeader = userAgentHeader;
    };
    ApiRequest.setXUserAgentHeader = function (xUserAgentHeader) {
        ApiRequest.xUserAgentHeader = xUserAgentHeader;
    };
    ApiRequest.userAgentHeader = '';
    ApiRequest.xUserAgentHeader = '';
    return ApiRequest;
}(Request));
export { ApiRequest };
//# sourceMappingURL=ApiRequest.js.map
```

The problem appears when trying to create `ApiRequest` object by calling `new ApiRequest(url)`, `Uncaught TypeError` is thrown with the following message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Request': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
>       at eval (eval at ApiRequest (ApiRequest.js:5), :1:1)

It appears that `Request` must not be called without `new` keyword, but the transpilled code does just that on line 5 (`_super.call()`).

Is there a way to get this working somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that finally worked is to wrap `Request` with a class-like function:

```
export const RequestWrapper: RequestWrapper = function(url: string, initialData?: any) {
    return new Request(url, initialData);
} as any;

export interface RequestWrapper extends Request {
    (url: string, initialData?: any): Request;
    new (url: string, initialData?: any): Request;
}
```

Then just extend `RequestWrapper` rather than `Request`:

```
export class ApiRequest extends RequestWrapper {
    ...
}
```